# Clean way to end the parsing of a bison parser

Tags: parsing, bison

I am writing a small expression analyser parser for a project at the company where I work. The parser is supposed to check, for example, a division by zero or an undefined identifier, report the error and stop. What is the best way to do this? Assuming that my own code has no memory leaks, can I simply do this:

```
if ($3 == 0) {
  yyerror("Division by zero");
  return 1;
}
```

should I rather do:

```
if ($3 == 0) {
  yyerror("Division by zero");
  YYERROR;
}
```

is there a third better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `yyerror` explicitly, how about using `YYABORT`?
As far as I see, `bison` seems to perform some cleanups at exit.
So, `YYABORT` or `YYERROR` will be more preferable to `return 1`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a third option indeed: `YYACCEPT`

If you are trying to stop the parsing because the input was valid and without errors(Since you are making a parser to detect errors, then it's not a parser error, the input did fit in the grammar's rules).

This leaves YYERROR for grammatical errors (like receiving a string from another language)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what needed to clean stop without errors